# How to change vertical touch scrolling to horizontal, but horizontal touch scrolling had to work normally on mobile website view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

My website has a horizontal layout. I have some problem with the mobile view.

What I want: If somebody want to touch scroll up or down the actual website should touch scroll left or right.

But If: somebody touch scroll horizontal that should work normally.

My current css:

```
.elementor-inner {
  touch-action: pan-x;
  height:100vw;

  overflow-y: scroll;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left; 
  position:absolute;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style:none;
  top: 0px;
  
}

.elementor-section-wrap {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left; 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  
  width: 700vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.section{ width:100vw; height:100vh}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
display:none;
}
```

My current website: https://bpro.hu/pro-sablon/fooldal-2/

Comment: You can implement normal touchstart-toucmove-touchend logic, just prevent the default action in the handlers if the move tends to be vertical, and move the layout manually in touchmove event handler.